# Status Messageboxes going behind the application

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-3.0

I have a situation like this..I have a windows application (Single threaded) that has one main form. After performing some operation, I'll get a message "Operation completed successfully" But most of the time it goes behind my application  and hence it is not visible.
Any idea why this is happening ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: any code for how are you showing messagebox?

Comment: MessageBox.Show("Checkin Successful.", "Linked2",MessageBoxButtons.OK);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
MessageBox.Show(this,"Your Message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use an overloaded method for [MessageBox.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx) that takes an IWin32Window and pass the currently visible form that you want your message box to appear on as parameter.